# Get list item values from SP.FileVersion object (JSOM)

Tags: jsom, versioning

Using the following JavaScript function, I am able to get all versions of a specified list item:

```
function getListItemVersions(listTitleOrId, listItemId) {
  let context = null;
  let web = null;
  try {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    let filePath = `/Lists/${listTitleOrId}/${listItemId}_.000`;
    let listItemInfo = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
    let listItemFields = listItemInfo.get_listItemAllFields();
    context.load(web);
    context.load(listItemInfo);
    context.load(listItemFields);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function (sender, args) {
        let fileVersions = listItemInfo.get_versions();
        context.load(fileVersions);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
          function (sender, args) {
            let objlistVersionEnumerator = fileVersions.getEnumerator();
            while (objlistVersionEnumerator.moveNext()) {
              let objCurrentListItemVersion =
                objlistVersionEnumerator.get_current();
              console.log(objCurrentListItemVersion);
            }    
          },
          function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Error getting versions from server', sender, args);
          }
        )    
      }, 
      function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Error getting list from server', sender, args);
      }
    );
  } catch(e) {
  }
}
```

For example, if I have a list called "Test List" which has an item with an ID of 23, I can call `getListItemVersions("Test List", 23)` and have all versions of the item logged. The problem is that I'm getting back objects of the type `SP.FileVersion`, i.e.:

[image]

Using the [`SP.FileVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245490.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returned, how can I get the values of the fields at each version of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't necessarily answer my question as asked, I did find an alternate method which allowed me to access all versions of a specific field from a specific list item by, modifying some good code from [here](https://github.com/shawnadrockleonard/development-samples/blob/master/Sample06/AppFiles/SiteAssets/js/SampleVersionDisp.js).

```
function getListItemVersions(listWebUrl, listName, listItemId, fieldName,
    onSuccess, onError) {
  var glisoapdef = new jQuery.Deferred();
  var soapHeader = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/';
  var soapAction = soapHeader + 'GetVersionCollection';
  var soapBody = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-'+
    'instance\' xmlns:xsd=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\' xmlns:soap=\'' +
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\'><soap:Body>' + 
    '<GetVersionCollection xmlns="' + soapHeader + '"><strlistID>' + listName +
    '</strlistID><strlistItemID>' + listItemId + '</strlistItemID><strFieldName>'+
    fieldName + '</strFieldName></GetVersionCollection></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

  $.ajax({
    url: listWebUrl + '/_vti_bin/lists.asmx',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function beforeSend(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', soapAction);
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: soapBody,
    contentType: "text/xml;charset='utf-8'",
    complete: function complete(xData, status) {
      var historyOptions = [];
      $(xData.responseText).find('Version').each(function (i) {
        var editorValue = '';
        var editor = $(this).attr('editor').split('#');
        if (editor.length >= 1) {
          editorValue = editor[1];
          var editorLen = editorValue.length;
          if (editorValue.lastIndexOf(',') == editorLen - 1) {
            editorValue = editorValue.substring(0, editorLen - 1);
          }
        }
        editor = editorValue.replace(',,', ',');
        historyOptions.push({
          Editor: editor,
          Modified: $(this).attr('Modified'),
          FieldValue: $(this).attr(fieldName)
        });
      });
      onSuccess(historyOptions);
      glisoapdef.resolve(historyOptions);
    },
    error: function error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
      glisoapdef.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
getListItemVersions('https://mycompany.sharepoint.com', 'List Name', 2308,
    'Field Name', function(items) {
  console.log(items);
  // do something with the items
});
```